# How to connect MySQL(RDBMS) with Hadoop Map Function

Tags: mysql, hadoop

I aleady knew I must use  DBInputFormat if I want to connect MySQL table and save data in HDFS

but, I don't want to use MySQL data like key and value that is used in Map Function

In other words, In my Map Function, I accept 'InputFormat' data in HDFS not RDBMS Data

and I want to transform data into new one using MySQL table

How can I do?

Comment: Why Map Reduce. You can use Apache sqoop to transfer MySQL data into HDFS. Using sqoop is a good and easy way to do it.

Comment: Your wording sounds like you want the **output** to be Mysql and the **input** to be HDFS?  Please clarify.

Comment: A(input data in HDFS)->Map->Reduce->B(output data, it will save in HDFS). In Map, I want to connect MySQL table. Thanks